# How can I place a customized button above an image view>

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to place a customized button above the image view, but doing that makes the button disappear. I'm doing all of this in Interface Builder. Is there any trick to make the button visible above the image view?

Comment: may i know why you want to add the button above the image view?

Comment: its like dis...i ve got four tab bars..my last tab has got an imageview covering the entire screen and i want to place 4 buttons above the image view....but adding buttons above the image view makes the button not visible...is it anyway possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create imageview programatically and set the frame. after that create uibutton also programatically and put that button in subview of imageview. Make sure make your imageview property Userinteraction Enabled TRUE.

for e.g.

```
    UIImageView *img1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"screen.png"]];
img1.frame = CGRectMake(50, 70, 100, 50);
[img1 setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
[self.view addSubview:img1];

UIButton *btn1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 50)];
btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn1 setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[img1 addSubview:btn1];
```

Answer (score 3):

use bringtofront in interface builder. First select the button which you want and then use bring to front in layout menu. Here is a screenshot

[image: BringToFront]

Answer (score 2):

I dont know much about Interface Builder. If you try to add both these programatically means it will work.
For adding image programmatically

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *image;   
    UIImage *image1=[UIImage imageNamed:@name.jpg"];  
    image=[[UIImageview alloc]initWithImage:image1];  
    image.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,400);  
    [self.view addSubview:image];  
    [image release];
```

For adding button programatically

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.view addSubview:button];
```